# Functional Scala programming pattern matching

Tags: scala, design-patterns, matching

Studying the Functional Programming book by Manning and struggling a bit.
Doesn't the below hasSubsequence fail because the first time it encounters the first `startsWith(sup, sub)` returning false the whole function `hasSubSequence` returns `false` at that point and it does not check the subsequent letters?

```
@annotation.tailrec
def startsWith[A](l: List[A], prefix: List[A]): Boolean = (l,prefix) match {
 case (_,Nil) => true
 case (Cons(h,t),Cons(h2,t2)) if h == h2 => startsWith(t, t2)
 case _ => false
}

@annotation.tailrec
def hasSubsequence[A](sup: List[A], sub: List[A]): Boolean = sup match {
 case Nil => sub == Nil
 case _ => startsWith(sup, sub)
 case Cons(h,t) => hasSubsequence(t, sub)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact example in the book? If yes, I think You're right, the wildcard case should be double checked or "if-guarded".

Comment: Can you please create [mcve]?

Comment: There is a list of Errata on the publisher website, but this one is not in there. Note that both authors of the book have left the Scala community a couple of years ago to work on [a new programming language](https://unisonweb.org/), so it is not clear whether they themselves will still have time to verify and publish Errata.